# Why isn't autocomplete feature of textbox adding new entries?

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocomplete

I have a textbox in an asp.net web site that has automatically stored previous entries. However, it no longer seems to be storing any new entries. This is annoying because I'm doing repeated testing using a new folder and don't want to have to manually retype the path every time I run it.

[image]

From what I've read online, this appears to be related to the [autocomplete](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_textbox_autocompletetype.asp) feature. I'm just wondering why it's no longer adding new entries? Is there a max number it can store/display?? Is there a way I can edit the values that pop up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok turns out the answer is that the autocomplete feature was only displaying the first six entries that had been stored. Thanks to [this article](http://lifehacker.com/5893908/how-to-banish-embarrassing-or-annoying-autocomplete-suggestions-from-your-browser) I was able to manually delete values by highlighting them and pressing Shift+Delete (works in Chrome and apparently Firefox too). This allowed new entries to be displayed.

[image]

**Edit:** Actually all it takes is Delete. Shift+Delete is apparently only necessary for Macs.

Reference: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Deleting_autocomplete_entries